# jQuery IDE to read and understand for jquery MIN verion

Tags: jquery

Please let me know that is there any jquery text editor(like IDE) to see jquery min version which is so difficult to read and understand.

Answer (score 3):

Just download the Development Version which is available from the jQuery Site.

For instance, here's [the link for 1.6.4 Development Version](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.js) (also known as Unminified))